# Interpolation Search, finding the closest value

Tags: c#

i am trying to use an Interpolation Search algorithm to find a value and return it. (Which is what it does currently). I am trying to modify it so it returns a number which i can use to find the closest values to the inputted item if the item which was searched was not found within the array.

```
public static int InterSearch(double[] array, double data)
        {
            int size = array.Length;
            int lo = 0;
            int mid = -1;
            int hi = array.Length - 1;
            int index = -1;
            int count = 0;

            while (lo <= hi)
            {
                mid = (int)(lo + (((double)(hi - lo) / (array[hi] - array[lo])) * (data - array[lo])));
                count++;
                if (array[mid] == data)
                {
                    index = mid;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (array[mid] < data)
                        lo = mid + 1;
                    else
                        hi = mid - 1;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }
```

Comment: so, return `lo` or `mid`.  That should give the caller the closest items (`lo` and `lo + 1`).  And it's easy enough to test if the item at `lo` is not what is being searched for.  You might have to adjust your algorithm slightly to make sure you always return the next lower entry.

Comment: What, specifically, do you think interpolation search gives you over binary search? Unless your seeks are very expensive (which is not the case with an in-memory array) it tends to be more complicated than necessary, and possibly slower. Even the largest array in .NET can't hold more than `int.MaxValue` elements, and the worst-case binary search would need no more than 32 iterations to find the nearest value searched for, *without* assuming a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate that find the closest value.
this is a custom extension method but you get the idea.

```
 public static double GetValueClosestTo(this List<double> values, double closestTo)
 {
     return values.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - closestTo) < Math.Abs(y - closestTo) ? x : y);
 }
```

Let's say you have the following array `{1, 5, 9.2, 6, 17}` and you test the following number `{6, 15, 5.2}`. You will use the following code

```
var sourceArray = new [] {1, 5, 9.2, 6, 17}.ToList() // for simplicity i use a list

var closestToX = sourceArray.GetValueClosestTo(6); // this return 6
closestToX = sourceArray.GetValueClosestTo(15); // this return 17
closestToX = sourceArray.GetValueClosestTo(5.2); // this return 5
```